# PostGIS, ST_Transform (no function exists..)

Tags: sql, buffer, transform, postgis, spatial

I have the following code to get 30m geometry shapes from a point layer already created

`CREATE TABLE intrsct_buff AS ( 
        SELECT ST_Transform(
                ST_Buffer(
                ST_Transform(pt.geom,4326)::geography,
                    30.0),
                    2263) as geom, pt.count
                    FROM public.intrsct_pts as pt
                    );`

I keep receiving the error: 
**LINE 3** `function st_transform(geography, integer) does not exist`
What do I need to add in front of `___,SRID 2263`? That seems to be the ST_Transform function where they say I have an error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to transform the geography back into geometry; `ST_Transform` does not work with `geography`:

```
CREATE TABLE intrsct_buff AS ( 
  SELECT
    ST_Transform(
      ST_Buffer(
        ST_Transform(
          pt.geom,
          4326
        )::geography,
        30.0
      )::geometry,
      2263
    ) as geom,
    pt.count
  FROM
    public.intrsct_pts as pt
);
```

Comment: That was all i needed! Thank you avocado I had been stuck on this for a while, will eat one of you tomorrow in appreciation!!

Comment: Awesome! Feast away! You can always check out the argument types for postgis functions in their docs, e.g., https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Transform.html