# Geomesa Pyspark AnalysisException: Undefined function: st_transform

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, geospatial, geomesa

I am trying to get the area of a bunch of polygons. I am able to use `st_area` and `st_geomFromText`, but I get an `undefined function` error when trying to use `st_transform`. I need to transform from 4326 to 3857 (or whatever will give me acres).

**geomesa version**: I had 2.4.2, but now I have 3.4.

**error**:

```
AnalysisException: Undefined function: st_transform. This function is neither a built-in/temporary function, nor a persistent function that is qualified as spark_catalog.default.st_transform.; line 4 pos 2
```

**code**:

```
%scala
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.locationtech.geomesa.spark.jts._
spark.withJTS
import org.locationtech.geomesa.spark.geotools._


%sql
select 
a.user_id
, Sum(st_area(st_geomFromText(a.polygon))) --this works
, Sum(st_transform(st_geomFromText(a.polygon), 'EPSG:4326','EPSG:3857')) --this does not work
from core_table a
group by a.user_id
```

I've tried changing the `fromCRS` and `toCRS` strings. I've tried using lowercase, different numbers, with/without quotes and letters, etc. I've tried encapsulating the st_transform() in a SUM(), but nothing works.

I've also tried something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61394153/postgis-st-transform-no-function-exists).

Answer (score 0):

The geometric functions are in a different package, because they require GeoTools and not just JTS. I believe you need to call `org.apache.spark.sql.SQLTypes#init` or equivalently `org.locationtech.geomesa.spark.GeometricDistanceFunctions#registerFunctions` to make them available.